# Malloc within same loop

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have two simple structs which in my main I create with:

```
struct Car *myCar[200]
struct Car *otherCar[200]
```

When I first tried to initialize them, I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    myCar[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Car*));
    otherCar[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Car*))
}
```

which doesn't work. but if I split them into separate loops like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
      myCar[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Car*));  
}

for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++){

    otherCar[x] = malloc(sizeof(struct Car*))
}
```

it works. Could somebody explain to me why it doesn't/does work in each examples?

Comment: What does not work mean?

Comment: you're missing a semicolon... and why allocating when you can do `struct Car myCar[200];` ? and that should work so [edit] your question to explain what goes wrong.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? Also you're allocating the wrong amount of memory. Your arrays contain pointers to `struct Car` but you're only allocating enough for a pointer, which probably isn't the size of the structure.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct Car*));` ==> `malloc(sizeof(struct Car));`. You created UB which was perhaps hidden (deferred!)  by moving the memory blocks for each array index away from each other.

Comment: The thing that wasn't working in the first method was that when I parsed data into the struct, it would give me junk values for the second struct but not the first

Comment: @FreeStyle4: It is called "undefined behavior". There's not much point in trying to analyze undefined behavior. For most means and purposes, it is non-deterministic.

Comment: @FreeStyle4 if you printed all the data after the entries were completed, no doubt the junk in the second case would be different from the junk in the first case, but still junk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the target pointer has `struct Car *` type, then most likely each call to `malloc` is supposed to allocate enough memory for a single `struct Car` object. Which means that the size of each memory block you allocate should be `sizeof(struct Car)`, not `sizeof(struct Car *)` as in your code.

This problem is present in both of your variants, which means that if the second one "works", it is a pure accident.

In general, a good idea would be to stick to the following idiom

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    myCar[i] = malloc(sizeof *myCar[i]);
    otherCar[i] = malloc(sizeof *otherCar[i]);
}
```

I.e. just add exactly one `*` in front of the recipient pointer and use it in `sizeof`. That way you do not have to count `*`s and worry about the specific type to use under `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(struct Car*)
```

this statement means the size of pointer 4 or 8 depending on the system, hence in your second option if it is working then it is sheer m/c luck.

you need to change it with b3low in both the variants

```
sizeof(struct Car);
```